# Detect keyboard events in games with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard-events

I want to make a macro for a game I'm playing, if I press a key on my keyboard I want to execute a sequence of keys.

And I want to know if there is a Python library that can do it.

I tried using Keyboard (pip install keyboard) but did not work so I checked their Github and I saw this: "Other applications, such as some games, may register hooks that swallow all key events. In this case keyboard will be unable to report events."

I found after a different implementation using pywin32 and pyhook but my antivirus and windows defender detects it as a keylogger and I can't even run the code in Visual Studio to see if it works, I think it is because of pyhook. Also I want my antivurus on

Thank you